# Android Studio how to get intent from a fragment?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

This is where I'm passing from:

```
public class AdapterForMainPage extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        String friendID;

        AdapterForMainPage(Context context) {

                super(context, R.layout.mainpagerow);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater friendsinflators = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                View custumView = friendsinflators.inflate(R.layout.mainpagerow, parent, false);

                final String friendID = getItem(position).toString();
                TextView friendsNameText = (TextView) custumView.findViewById(R.id.txtUsersNameMainPage);
                ImageButton lockImageButton = (ImageButton)custumView.findViewById(R.id.btnLock);

                friendsNameText.setText(friendID);
                lockImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.lockdefault);

                lockImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intentId = new Intent(getContext(), Message.class);
                            intentId.putExtra("friendID", friendID);
                            getContext().startActivity(intentId);

                            Intent intentMessageAdapter= new Intent(getContext(), AdapterForMessageList.class);
                            intentMessageAdapter.putExtra("friendID", friendID);
                        }
                });

                return custumView;
        }
}
```

This is where I'm trying to pass it to

```
public class AdapterForMessageList extends ArrayAdapter {

    public AdapterForMessageList(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.message_array);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater messageInflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View custumView = messageInflator.inflate(R.layout.message_array, parent, false);

        DatabaseReference currentmessagefield;
        String currentUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().toString();


        String messageKey = getItem(position).toString();


        currentmessagefield = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("Friend").child(friendbID).child("Messages").child(messageKey);

        TextView txtMessage = (TextView)custumView.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        txtMessage.setText(FriendUsername);

        return custumView;
    }
}
```

The `getIntent` does not work.  So doesn't get activity

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to acchive here. Please edit the question to to provide as minimal a code example as required, state what you're trying to acchive and show what you have tried already.

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intentMessageAdapter= new Intent(getContext(), AdapterForMessageList.class);
                        intentMessageAdapter.putExtra("friendID", friendID);
```

You are missing the line to start activity

```
getContext().startActivity(intentMessageAdapter);
```

To get the intent inside your fragment you will have to use `getAcivity().getIntent`....;

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful

Comment: Actually within the fragment I am unable to use the getActivity.getIntent

Comment: AdapterForMessageList this class is extends to an arrayadapter which is used to provide data to listviews,gridview etc.You will have to make an fragement which contains a listview and then from their you can pass it to the adapter of that view.